# Column out of Reference Google Sheet / Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with 20 columns.
When I try to delete column 3 to 12 I get the error:

> Columns out of Reference..

I am using the following code:

```
// Setup sheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var importSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var importSheetLastRow = importSheet.getLastRow();
var workingSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
var workingSheetLastRow = workingSheet.getLastRow();
var chaufSheet = ss.getSheets()[2];
var chaufSheetLastRow = chaufSheet.getLastRow();

// Copy data to export range
var copyData = importSheet.getRange(20, 1, importSheetLastRow, 20);
copyData.copyTo(workingSheet.getRange(1,1));

// Delete unneeded data
workingSheet.deleteColumns(3, 10);
workingSheet.deleteColumns(4, 4);
```

Strange thing is: every first time I run the script, it gives the error. When I rerun the script, it works fine.. I also tried using `try {}` and `catch(e){}` but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in this part

```
// Copy data to export range
var copyData = importSheet.getRange(20, 1, importSheetLastRow, 20);
copyData.copyTo(workingSheet.getRange(1,1));
```

Here you're storing range of size `[importSheetLastRow * 20]` that means it will refer to cells starting from `(20,1)` and will strech to size of `[importSheetLastRow * 20]`

But when you're copying it to `workingSheet` you're only giving range of 1 cell that's `(1,1)` top-right most cell.

There is discrepancy. Both range should be of same **dimensions**

I think this will work

```
// Copy data to export range
var copyData = importSheet.getRange(20, 1, importSheetLastRow, 20);
copyData.copyTo(workingSheet.getRange(1, 1, importSheetLastRow, 20));
```

And your error `Column out of reference` maybe coming because that's cell is never populated/inflated. Try this first, if same error keeps coming then we can debug further.

If you get any further error kindly provide more informations like in which line error is coming, etc

Comment: thanks for your response, but it's not working. Still getting the error on the first run, second run the script runs fine, third run I get the error etc..

Comment: I solved the problem by copying just the columns I need instead of deleting those I don't need.